# What "transition" is Paul referring to?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

In *Dune* (2021), Thufir showed Paul silos which are used to hold spice:

> Thufir: These are spice silos. We're meant to fill every crate.
>
> Paul: All of them?
>
> Thufir: Every 25 standard days. Harkonnen sabotage slows us down.
>
> Paul: But who's meant to arbitrate? Isn't there a Judge of the Change
> to oversee **the transition**?

What "transition" is Paul referring to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 'transition' is the process of change in planetary leadership of Arrakis from the Harkonnen to the Atreides. This is arbitrated by Kynes, the Imperial Planetologist who is acting as '*Judge of the Change*' with power and authority to call shenanigans if the Harkonnen get caught cheating.

> “As you wish,” the Duke said. He glanced down at Paul. “Son, this is
> the Judge of the Change, the arbiter of dispute, the man set here to
> see that the forms are obeyed in our assumption of power over this
> fief.” He glanced at Kynes. “And this is my son.”
>
> <sub><sup>Dune</sup></sub>

Theoretically, the Harkonnen are supposed to arrange for an orderly takeover, leaving in place both equipment and personnel. In reality they do everything they can, short of *open* malfeasance to make the transition as difficult as possible in the hopes that this will distract the Atreides leadership from the genuine attack that is to be enacted shortly.

> ”We will have to take it at the point of the sword,“ Leto said. He
> turned to Hawat. ”This’d be a good point to report on equipment. How
> many sandcrawlers, harvesters, spice factories, and supporting
> equipment have they left us?“
>
> ”A full complement, as it says in the Imperial inventory audited by
> the Judge of the Change, my Lord,“ Hawat said. He gestured for an aide
> to pass him a folder, opened the folder on the table in front of him.
> ”They neglect to mention that less than half the crawlers are
> operable, that only about a third have carryalls to fly them to spice
> sands–that everything the Harkonnens left us is ready to break down
> and fall apart. We’ll be lucky to get half the equipment into
> operation and luckier yet if a fourth of it’s still working six months
> from now.“